# Is it possible to iterate Typescript class abstract methods in run-time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I need to know a list of abstract methods (actually all methods including abstract ones) of the class. Is it possible to do somehow using Typescript?

```
export abstract class INotificationService {
     abstract dismissRequested();
}

console.log(Object.getMethodsList(INotificationService));
```

Expected result: ['dismissRequested', ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code generated for an abstract method, so there is no direct way to get the methods. You can create a dummy implementation and get the functions from that:

```
abstract class INotificationService {

    abstract dismissRequested(): void;
}

function getMethods<T>(cls: new (...args: any[]) => T): string[] {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cls.prototype).filter(c=> c!=="constructor");
}

var methods = getMethods<INotificationService>(class extends INotificationService {
    dismissRequested(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
});
```

If we want we can make this a bit safer by forbidding the dummy implementation class to have any new methods. This will prevent us from forgetting old methods that we removed from the abstract class, although it is possible for the dummy implementation to override existing class methods that are not abstract, so use with care:

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
function getMethods<T>(): <TResult>(cls: new (...args: any[]) => TResult & { [ P in Diff<keyof TResult, keyof T>]: never }) => string[] {
    return cls => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cls.prototype).filter(c=> c!=="constructor");
}

abstract class INotificationService {

    abstract dismissRequested(): void;
    nonAbstarct(): void {}
}
var methods = getMethods<INotificationService>()(class extends INotificationService {
    // Implement abstract methods, although it is possible to add other methods as well and the compiler will not complain 
    dismissRequested(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
});


// Will cause an error
var methods2 = getMethods<INotificationService>()(class extends INotificationService {
    dismissRequested(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    } 
    oldDismissRequested(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
});
// Will NOT cause an error
var methods3 = getMethods<INotificationService>()(class extends INotificationService {
    dismissRequested(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    } 
    nonAbstarct(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
});
```